# Rounded corners on only one side of a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make rounded corners on one side of my node (only right, only left)?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [fill=gray, rounded corners=10pt]{

        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is possible with the `rounded rectangle` shape type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={fill=gray, rounded rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm}]
    \node [](A){};
    \node [rounded rectangle west arc=none, below=of A](B){};
    \node [rounded rectangle east arc=none, below=of B]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screen shot of results]

See Section 48.8 of the TikZ Manual for further options.

Answer (score 13):

Above method only allowing east or west non-rounding. I needed that and was not satisfied with the answer.

So we have to adopt method from other solution ([Rounded corners in TikZ trees.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/rounded-corners-in-tikz-trees)) and make customized differently rounded corners.

I would be grateful if someone includes this in future TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
  rectangle corner radius north west/.initial=10pt,
  rectangle corner radius north east/.initial=10pt,
  rectangle corner radius south west/.initial=10pt,
  rectangle corner radius south east/.initial=10pt
}
\newif\ifpgf@rectanglewrc@donecorner@
\def\pgf@rectanglewithroundedcorners@docorner#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \edef\pgf@marshal{%
    \noexpand\pgfintersectionofpaths
      {%
        \noexpand\pgfpathmoveto{\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}}%
        \noexpand\pgfpathlineto{\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
      }%
      {%
        \noexpand\pgfpathmoveto{\noexpand\pgfpointadd
          {\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@yc}}%
          {\noexpand\pgfpoint{#1}{#2}}}%
        \noexpand\pgfpatharc{#3}{#4}{#5}%
      }%
    }%
  \pgf@process{\pgf@marshal\pgfpointintersectionsolution{1}}%
  \pgf@process{\pgftransforminvert\pgfpointtransformed{}}%
  \pgf@rectanglewrc@donecorner@true
}
\pgfdeclareshape{rectangle with rounded corners}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}

  \savedmacro\cornerradiusnw{%
    \edef\cornerradiusnw{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/rectangle corner radius north west}}%
  }
  \savedmacro\cornerradiusne{%
    \edef\cornerradiusne{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/rectangle corner radius north east}}%
  }
  \savedmacro\cornerradiussw{%
    \edef\cornerradiussw{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/rectangle corner radius south west}}%
  }
  \savedmacro\cornerradiusse{%
    \edef\cornerradiusse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/rectangle corner radius south east}}%
  }

  \backgroundpath{%
    \northeast\advance\pgf@y-\cornerradiusne\relax
    \pgfpathmoveto{}%
    \pgfpatharc{0}{90}{\cornerradiusne}%
    \northeast\pgf@ya=\pgf@y\southwest\advance\pgf@x\cornerradiusnw\relax\pgf@y=\pgf@ya
    \pgfpathlineto{}%
    \pgfpatharc{90}{180}{\cornerradiusnw}%
    \southwest\advance\pgf@y\cornerradiussw\relax
    \pgfpathlineto{}%
    \pgfpatharc{180}{270}{\cornerradiussw}%
    \northeast\pgf@xa=\pgf@x\advance\pgf@xa-\cornerradiusse\southwest\pgf@x=\pgf@xa
    \pgfpathlineto{}%
    \pgfpatharc{270}{360}{\cornerradiusse}%
    \northeast\advance\pgf@y-\cornerradiusne\relax
    \pgfpathlineto{}%
    \pgfpathclose
  }

  \anchor{before north east}{\northeast\advance\pgf@y-\cornerradiusne}
  \anchor{after north east}{\northeast\advance\pgf@x-\cornerradiusne}
  \anchor{before north west}{\southwest\pgf@xa=\pgf@x\advance\pgf@xa\cornerradiusnw
    \northeast\pgf@x=\pgf@xa}
  \anchor{after north west}{\northeast\pgf@ya=\pgf@y\advance\pgf@ya-\cornerradiusnw
    \southwest\pgf@y=\pgf@ya}
  \anchor{before south west}{\southwest\advance\pgf@y\cornerradiussw}
  \anchor{after south west}{\southwest\advance\pgf@x\cornerradiussw}
  \anchor{before south east}{\northeast\pgf@xa=\pgf@x\advance\pgf@xa-\cornerradiusse
    \southwest\pgf@x=\pgf@xa}
  \anchor{after south east}{\southwest\pgf@ya=\pgf@y\advance\pgf@ya\cornerradiusse
    \northeast\pgf@y=\pgf@ya}

  \anchorborder{%
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x% xb/yb is target
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    \southwest%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x% xa/ya is se
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \northeast%
    \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xa%
    \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@ya%
    \pgf@xc=.5\pgf@x% x/y is half width/height
    \pgf@yc=.5\pgf@y%
    \advance\pgf@xa by\pgf@xc% xa/ya becomes center
    \advance\pgf@ya by\pgf@yc%
    \edef\pgf@marshal{%
      \noexpand\pgfpointborderrectangle
      {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xb}{\the\pgf@yb}}
      {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@yc}}%
    }%
    \pgf@process{\pgf@marshal}%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa% 
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@ya%
    \pgfextract@process\borderpoint{}%
    %
    \pgf@rectanglewrc@donecorner@false
    %
    % do southwest corner
    \southwest\pgf@xc=\pgf@x\pgf@yc=\pgf@y
    \advance\pgf@xc\cornerradiussw\relax\advance\pgf@yc\cornerradiussw\relax 
    \borderpoint
    \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@xc\relax\ifdim\pgf@y<\pgf@yc\relax
      \pgf@rectanglewithroundedcorners@docorner{-\cornerradiussw}{0pt}{180}{270}{\cornerradiussw}%
    \fi\fi
    %
    % do southeast corner
    \ifpgf@rectanglewrc@donecorner@\else
      \southwest\pgf@yc=\pgf@y\relax\northeast\pgf@xc=\pgf@x\relax
      \advance\pgf@xc-\cornerradiusse\relax\advance\pgf@yc\cornerradiusse\relax
      \borderpoint
      \ifdim\pgf@x>\pgf@xc\relax\ifdim\pgf@y<\pgf@yc\relax
       \pgf@rectanglewithroundedcorners@docorner{0pt}{-\cornerradiusse}{270}{360}{\cornerradiusse}%
      \fi\fi
    \fi
    %
    % do northeast corner
    \ifpgf@rectanglewrc@donecorner@\else
      \northeast\pgf@xc=\pgf@x\relax\pgf@yc=\pgf@y\relax
      \advance\pgf@xc-\cornerradiusne\relax\advance\pgf@yc-\cornerradiusne\relax
      \borderpoint
      \ifdim\pgf@x>\pgf@xc\relax\ifdim\pgf@y>\pgf@yc\relax
       \pgf@rectanglewithroundedcorners@docorner{\cornerradiusne}{0pt}{0}{90}{\cornerradiusne}%
      \fi\fi
    \fi
    %
    % do northwest corner
    \ifpgf@rectanglewrc@donecorner@\else
      \northeast\pgf@yc=\pgf@y\relax\southwest\pgf@xc=\pgf@x\relax
      \advance\pgf@xc\cornerradiusnw\relax\advance\pgf@yc-\cornerradiusnw\relax
      \borderpoint
      \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@xc\relax\ifdim\pgf@y>\pgf@yc\relax
       \pgf@rectanglewithroundedcorners@docorner{0pt}{\cornerradiusnw}{90}{180}{\cornerradiusnw}%
      \fi\fi
    \fi
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node(rc)[
    rectangle with rounded corners,draw=yellow, fill=yellow!10,align=center,rectangle corner radius north west=0pt]
    {\large rectangle with rounded corners\\\large rectangle with rounded corners\\\large rectangle with rounded corners};%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've added an image with the output from your code. Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, consider registering to the site, so you can contribute more to it.

Comment: Thank you. Now i want to use that as clipping path and it doesnt work, so now I will try to post a question...

Comment: Cool stuff, Khaj. For integration into TikZ, I suggest to turn this into a tikz library (loadable with `\usetikzlibrary`). I don't know how the process is to get something into TikZ CVS, but it might be worth a try. Another option is to publish this on the tex.se package site [("From answers to packages")](https://launchpad.net/tex-sx).

Comment: Doesn't work well, try this and look at the north east corner:
\draw node[
 rectangle with rounded corners,draw=yellow, fill=yellow!10,align=center,rectangle corner radius south west=0pt, rectangle corner radius south east=0pt](rr) at (0,-4)
 {\large rectangle with rounded corners\\\large rectangle with rounded corners\\\large rectangle with rounded corners};

Comment: @Álvaro, in the ``\backgroundpath`` after the ``\pgfpatharc{180}{270}`` line it should use ``\cornerradiusse`` instead of ``\cornerradiussw``. Also, added ``\pgfpathclose`` to close the figure (fixing the corner join if it's a 0pt arc). I've applied the changes to the answer code.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to have the same need, and for me it worked to draw a line around the text node, using the very node anchors to encompass it, and y/x shift to leave a blank space. That space I would use to draw an arc.

The offset should be the same as the circle controls, but it showed a small edge, so the right control set to 2.5mm gave a better looking result.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[align = center, minimum height = 0.8cm] (rect) {
          one round corner rectangle
        };
        \draw[] ([xshift = -0.2cm]rect.north east) -- (rect.north west) -- (rect.south west) -- (rect.south east) -- ([yshift = -0.2cm]rect.north east);
        \draw[] ([xshift = -0.2cm]rect.north east) .. controls +(right: 2.5mm) and +(down: 2mm) .. ([yshift = -0.2cm]rect.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This showed:

[image]