# Different radii of rounded corners in same draw command in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

Is it possible to use different rounded corners radii on different parts of a draw command?

I'm creating a tube that is bent. I'd like the outer radius to be greater than the inner radius. I can of course do this by creating two different draw commands, but then I won't be able to fill the object.

```
\filldraw[draw=blue!50, fill=black!10, rounded corners=2] (1.9,15) -- (3.1,15) -- (3.1,14.6)
-- (3.3,14.6) -- (3.3,15.2) -- (3.5,15.2)-- (3.5,13.9) -- (3.3,13.9) --(3.3,14.5) --
(3.1,14.5) -- (3.1,14.1) -- (1.9,14.1) -- cycle;
```

I've tried the following, but it generated a white diamond-shape in the middle of the figure that was supposed to be green.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\filldraw node[fill=green,
append after command={[rounded corners=0pt](b.west)|-(b.north)},
append after command={[rounded corners=3pt](b.north)-|(b.east)},
append after command={[rounded corners=1pt](b.east)|-(b.south)},
append after command={[rounded corners=5pt](b.south)-|(b.west)}] (b) {Another piece of text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TikZ rectangular node with different rounded corners](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32867/tikz-rectangular-node-with-different-rounded-corners)

Comment: If the above linked question does not solve your issue, please update the question as to why. Otherwise this will probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterGrill Even if I use the method described in the answer to the question linked, I still can't use filldraw as far as I can tell. If I would't fill the shape the other solution would work.

Comment: Oh, that didn't format very well. How am I supposed to give you the code?

Comment: @Hugo At the bottom of your question is an “Edit” button. You can add this code to your question. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Also, please add `@<user>` to your comment (as I did in mine) so that the author of the comment you’re responding to will be notified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the `rounded corners` key can be specified at several points along the path with different values by adding `[rounded corners=<value>]` in the path, which will then be active until the end of the path or until the next `rounded corners` key. Alternatively, as Qrrbirlbel pointed out in a comment, you can also keep the option local to part of the path by enclosing it in `{ ... }`. I've used both approaches in the example below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[draw=blue!50, fill=black!10, rounded corners=3] (1.9,15)
-- (3.1,15) {[rounded corners=1]
-- (3.1,14.6) 
-- (3.3,14.6)}
-- (3.3,15.2)
-- (3.5,15.2)
-- (3.5,13.9)
-- (3.3,13.9) [rounded corners=1]
-- (3.3,14.5)
-- (3.1,14.5) [rounded corners=3]
-- (3.1,14.1) -- (1.9,14.1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a list of settings which can be used this way? It doesn't work for line width or line color I assume.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Ah, that would be useful indeed. No, it doesn't work for colour, width, `line join`, or most other options. I think it only works for things that have more to do with path construction (`radius` for circles, for example) than with the actual path representation.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Unfortunately, the PGF manual is very unspecific about that (section 14: “Some options […]”). @Jake you might add, that this option can also be “scoped” which removes the need to repeat `rounded corners=3`, e.g. `\path[rounded corners=3] <radius is 3> { [rounded corners=1] <radius is 1> }
<radius is 3 again>;`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Good point! I've edited my answer. Thanks!