# TikZ: different rounded-corner radii of a horizontal-vertical path with two turns

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a horizontal-vertical path between two nodes, with different radii of rounded corners.

Here's my original code (single-radius):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta,mindmap,shadows,backgrounds,calc,positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{Arrow/.style={-{stealth},very thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners,minimum width=22mm},
    every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,5) {B};

\draw[Arrow,rounded corners=5pt]
    % start at source
    (A)
    % go right and up to anchor
    -| ($ (B.south) - (18.5mm,3mm) $)
    % go right and up to target
    -| ([xshift=-7mm]B.south)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

Now I would like the first turn to have a larger radius. The **expected results** should look like the following (please ignore the imperfections due to my bad GIMP skills):

[image]

I followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98979/24048) to set a different radius for the first turn:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta,mindmap,shadows,backgrounds,calc,positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{Arrow/.style={-{stealth},very thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners,minimum width=22mm},
    every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,5) {B};

\draw[Arrow,rounded corners=5pt]
    % start at source
    (A)
    % go right and up to anchor
        { [rounded corners=30pt]
        -| ($ (B.south) - (18.5mm,3mm) $)
        }
    % go right and up to target
    -| ([xshift=-7mm]B.south)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Results are not as expected:

[image]

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three turns, but only two are explicit.  TikZ intuits the third.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta,mindmap,shadows,backgrounds,calc,positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{Arrow/.style={-{stealth},very thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum width=22mm},
    every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,5) {B};

\draw[Arrow,rounded corners=30pt]
    % start at source
    (A)
    % go right and up to midpoint
    -| ($ (B.south) - (18.5mm,2.5) $)
    % got up and right to the anchor
    [rounded corners=5pt]
    |- ($ (B.south) - (12mm,3mm) $)
    % go right and up to target
    -| ([xshift=-7mm]B.south)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version uses corners instead of midpoints.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta,mindmap,shadows,backgrounds,calc,positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{Arrow/.style={-{stealth},very thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum width=22mm},
    every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,5) {B};

\coordinate (AB) at ($ (B.south) - (18.5mm,3mm) $); % for simplicity
\coordinate (BB) at ([xshift=-7mm]B.south);

\draw[Arrow,rounded corners=30pt]
    % start at source
    (A) -- (A -| AB) % first corner
    [rounded corners=5pt]
     -- (AB) -- (AB -| BB) -- (BB);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Woah, why didn't I think about this before? Perfect answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not generic :( I changed the second to to `\node (B) at (5,2.5) {B};` and couldn't find parameters that give an acceptable result :( Could you please have a look?

Comment: To find a midpoint, add the coordinates of the corners and divide by 2, or use `(A!0.5!B)` (calc tikzlibrary).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oops, make that `($(A)!0.5!(B)$)`.

Comment: I used your second version so I didn't try the midpoint :D

Comment: I've just tried midpoint but the results are bad (there's an extra line). Your second solution is excellent though.

Comment: Remember, this is for posterity.

Comment: Sure, you are right. Thank you again!