# Fill a node shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to fill a custom shaped node but as can be observed in the example below the fill does not occur naturally rather it uses its default shape to fill. Any insights?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (\textwidth-0.4pt, 0) node[
    fill=blue!20,
    append after command={[rounded corners=0pt](b.west)|-(b.north)},
    append after command={[rounded corners=0pt](b.north)-|(b.east)},
    append after command={[rounded corners=1pt](b.east)|-(b.south)},
    append after command={[rounded corners=5pt](b.south)-|(b.west)},
    anchor=north west,
    at start,
    text=white] 
(b) {Example} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would go with Roelof's shape if compared to Ignasi's ;)

Comment: Link to question where sample code was gotten is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32867/10898

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Insight: The `fill` is used for the actual `rectangle` shape. The `append after command` is just appended to the path and uses the style of the `\draw` (no filling).

Although [Roelof Spijker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32869/16595) has given an excellent solution, here’s a fix by using one full path.

### Code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\tikzset{weird fill/.style={append after command={
    \pgfextra
        \draw[sharp corners, fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.west) |- (\tikzlastnode.north east) [rounded corners=1pt] |- (\tikzlastnode.south) [rounded corners=5pt] -|  (\tikzlastnode.north west) -- cycle;
    \endpgfextra}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (\textwidth-0.4pt, 0) node [
    weird fill=blue!20,
    anchor=north west,
    at start,
    text=white] {Example} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: What does `\pgfextra` do?

Comment: @azetina The PGF manual tells us (note that `\pgfextra{<code>}` and `\pgfextra <code> \endpgfextra` is the same): “This command may only be used inside a TikZ path. There it is used like a normal path operation. The construction of the path is temporarily suspended and the `<code>` is executed. Then, the path construction is resumed.” The `append after command` entry will be used in the middle of a path and this would result in an error as we would have had `\draw <stuff> \draw <inner stuff>; <other stuff>;`.