# Tikz shape similar to rectangle with selective drawing of borders

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, pgf-core

I am looking for a `tikz` shape similar to the rectangle shape, but with the possibility of drawing individual borders selectively. Also when used with rounded corners, the corners missing a border should not be rounded.

The following image illustrates what I want when the bottom border is not drawn.

[image: shape with missing border]

Any clues on how to get this shape?

Comment: You need an algorithm that takes a list of sides that should be drawn a sequence of `\pgfpathlineto` and `\pgfpathmoveto` commands (where to start, where to end, etc). Do you have an idea on how to do that? There are `2^4` possibilities (including no border at all and a full border). (I started something like this but I cannot find it anymore.)

Comment: Meanwhile: [Cut one side of a rectangle node in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82279)

Answer (score 16):

A brute-force attempt.

The versions where only one or two opposite sides are drawn wouldn’t have a correct area to fill. One will need to use the special `\behindbackgroundpath` for this. The same is true for the other versions with two adjacent sides: they create a triangular area.

But you then need to use an extra key: `/pgf/open rectangle fill`. You can disable the filling with `open rectangle fill=`, i.e. an empty input. If you want to use TikZ options here (like shading, fading or such, this will get a little bit more complicated but would be doable, too.

As requested, I put the code for this shape in its own library. The files

- [`tikzlibraryqrr.shapes.openrectangle.code.tex`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibraryqrr.shapes.openrectangle.code.tex) and
- [`pgflibraryqrr.shapes.openrectangle.code.tex`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/pgflibraryqrr.shapes.openrectangle.code.tex).

The TikZ library only contains an `\usepgflibrary` to the PGF library which contains the actual code.

---

For the option `open rectangle sides=full` the usual background path of a `rectangle` is used. The same is true, if the value of `open rectangle sides` is empty. (If you want no border drawn, don’t use `draw`.) This also shows how to create aliases:

```
\let\pgf@sh@openrectangle@<new name>\pgf@sh@openrectangle@<old name>
```

say, for example

```
\let\pgf@sh@openrectangle@tab\pgf@sh@openrectangle@enw
```

The naming scheme is pretty easy: all sides starting from the `e`astern (counter-clockwise) side are specified:

- `e` draws the eastern side.
- `ew` draws the eastern and western side.
- `ews` draws the the western, the southern and the eastern side (a cup).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains} \usetikzlibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}
\tikzset{nodes={rounded corners, text height=\heightof{f}, text width=\widthof{aaaa}, ultra thick, draw, open rectangle fill=blue!40, shape=open rectangle,
  append after command={(\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[to path={rectangle (\tikztotarget)}, very thin] (\tikzlastnode.north east)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.1cm, Start chain/.style={start chain=ch#1 going below}, Start chain/.list={1,...,4}, node distance=+2pt]\ttfamily
\foreach \ch/\si in {1/{e, n, w, s},
                     2/{nws, ews, ens, enw},
                     3/{en, nw, ws, es},
                     4/{, full, ew, ns}}
  \foreach \Si in \si
    \node[at=(right:\ch), on chain=ch\ch, open rectangle sides=\Si] {\Si};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I would like to be able to fill the full area of the shape, independently of which borders are drawn. Your solution does that only for the cases with 3 or 4 borders. Could you please complete this feature for 0, 1 and 2 borders? Unfortunately I do not have the skill to program with `tikz` at this level yet. You mentioned the need to use a special `\behindbackgroundpath` for this.

Comment: I would like also to suggest to separate the code into two pieces: a `tikz` library (let's say `tikzlibraryopenrectangle.code.tex`) and a demonstration document.

Comment: @Romildo See my updated answer.

Answer (score 15):

I tried an approach with Tikz, by drawing a line around an existing node and turning that into a newcommand. You can change almost everything according to your needs.

The only exception is relative positioning. I'm still having a problem with it because I can't seem to make it work. I've tried different tweaks but I haven't found the solution yet. (If someone sees what I'm missing, please let me know.)

The only workaround for now is that, if you leave a blank line between the two commands, it will draw the node below the other one, if you leave no lines, they will be positioned one next to the other one.

[image: rectangle image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc,calc}

\tikzset{newnode/.style={inner sep=2mm, text depth=.5mm},
}

\newcommand{\newtab}[4]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[newnode, #2] (#1) {#4};
        \draw[draw=black, rounded corners, thick, #3]  ($(#1.south west)+(0mm,0mm)$) 
                -- ($(#1.north west)+(0mm,0mm)$)
                -- ($(#1.north east)+(0mm,0mm)$)
                -- ($(#1.south east)+(0mm,0mm)$);
    \node[newnode, #2] (#1) {#4};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

% node name, positiong (doesn't work yet), line properties, node text

\newtab{test}{}{fill=red!20}{This is a test}
\newtab{test2}{}{fill=blue!20}{This is another test} 
\newtab{test3}{}{fill=green!20}{This is yet another test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Next solution is inspired in [Qrrbrbirlbel's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101085/1952) to [Fill a node shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101079/fill-a-node-shape), although in this case we need two different orders to `fill` and `draw`the shape.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    bottomflat/.style={
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                \fill[fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.south west) [rounded corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.north) -| (\tikzlastnode.east) [sharp corners] |- cycle;
                \draw[rounded corners] (\tikzlastnode.south west) |- (\tikzlastnode.north) -| (\tikzlastnode.south east);
            \endpgfextra}},
    topflat/.style={
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                \fill[fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.north east) [rounded corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.south) -| (\tikzlastnode.west) [sharp corners] |- cycle;
                \draw[rounded corners] (\tikzlastnode.north east) |- (\tikzlastnode.south) -| (\tikzlastnode.north west);
            \endpgfextra}},
    leftflat/.style={
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                \fill[fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.north west) [rounded corners] -| (\tikzlastnode.east) |- (\tikzlastnode.south) [sharp corners] -| cycle;
                \draw[rounded corners] (\tikzlastnode.north west) -| (\tikzlastnode.east) |- (\tikzlastnode.south west);
            \endpgfextra}},
    rightflat/.style={
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                \fill[fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.south east) [rounded corners] -| (\tikzlastnode.west) |- (\tikzlastnode.north) [sharp corners] -| cycle;
                \draw[rounded corners] (\tikzlastnode.south east) -| (\tikzlastnode.west) |- (\tikzlastnode.north east);
            \endpgfextra}}]

\path node[bottomflat=blue!20] (A) {This is a test};
\path node[topflat=green!20, below=3mm of A] (B) {This is a test};
\path node[leftflat=red!20, below=3mm of B] (C) {This is a test};
\path node[rightflat=purple!20, below=3mm of C] (D) {This is a test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Previous code works with [TikZ 3.0.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) but it fails with TiKZ 2.10. In this case you need to use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    bottomflat/.style={
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                \fill[fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.south west) [rounded corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.north) -| (\tikzlastnode.east) [sharp corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.south)-- cycle;
                \draw[rounded corners] (\tikzlastnode.south west) |- (\tikzlastnode.north) -| (\tikzlastnode.south east);
            \endpgfextra}},
    topflat/.style={
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                \fill[fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.north east) [rounded corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.south) -| (\tikzlastnode.west) [sharp corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.north west)--cycle;
                \draw[rounded corners] (\tikzlastnode.north east) |- (\tikzlastnode.south) -| (\tikzlastnode.north west);
            \endpgfextra}},
    leftflat/.style={
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                \fill[fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.north west) [rounded corners] -| (\tikzlastnode.east) |- (\tikzlastnode.south) [sharp corners] -| (\tikzlastnode.south west)--cycle;
                \draw[rounded corners] (\tikzlastnode.north west) -| (\tikzlastnode.east) |- (\tikzlastnode.south west);
            \endpgfextra}},
    rightflat/.style={
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra
                \fill[fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.south east) [rounded corners] -| (\tikzlastnode.west) |- (\tikzlastnode.north) [sharp corners] -| (\tikzlastnode.north east)--cycle;
                \draw[rounded corners] (\tikzlastnode.south east) -| (\tikzlastnode.west) |- (\tikzlastnode.north east);
            \endpgfextra}}]

\path node[bottomflat=blue!20] (A) {This is a test};
\path node[topflat=green!20, below=3mm of A] (B) {This is a test};
\path node[leftflat=red!20, below=3mm of B] (C) {This is a test};
\path node[rightflat=purple!20, below=3mm of C] (D) {This is a test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile here: `! Argument of \tikz@collect@coordinate@onpath has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.32 ...[bottomflat=blue!20] (A) {This is a test};`

Comment: The `\draw` part is not correct. For `topflat`, use `\fill[fill=#1] (\tikzlastnode.north east) [rounded corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.south)  -| (\tikzlastnode.west) [sharp corners] |- (\tikzlastnode.north) -- cycle;`

Comment: @mort I don't understand where is the problem. There is no need to include `(\tikzlastnode.north)` between `(\tikzlastnode.west) [sharp corners]` and `cycle` if you use `|-` instead of `--`.

Comment: @Ignasi: Like Romildo said, your code does not compile

Comment: @mort. You're right. I'm always using cvs version and sometimes forget to test solutions with 2.10. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Given the popularity of tikz on this site, this is a good example to show that tikz also works nicely with ConTeXt (though, the interface is not as pretty).

```
\usemodule[tikz]

\define\tikztopframe
  {\starttikzpicture
    \draw[
           \overlaylinecolor, 
           line width=\overlaylinewidth,
           fill=\overlaycolor,
           rounded corners,
         ]
      (0,0)--  (0,\overlayheight) -- (\overlaywidth,\overlayheight) -- (\overlaywidth, 0) ;
  \stoptikzpicture}

\defineoverlay[topframe][\tikztopframe]

\defineframed
  [topframe]
  [
    frame=off,
    location=low,
    background=topframe,
    backgroundcolor=yellow,
    framecolor=red,
  ]

\starttext
  Test
  \topframe[rulethickness=2pt]{This is a test}
  \topframe[backgroundcolor=green]{Another test}
  Test
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]