# Issue with `pgflibrary` and MiKTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, miktex, nodes

After reading "[Tikz shape similar to rectangle with selective drawing of borders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140842/tikz-shape-similar-to-rectangle-with-selective-drawing-of-borders)," I tried to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains} \usetikzlibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}
\tikzset{nodes={rounded corners, text height=\heightof{f}, text width=\widthof{aaaa}, ultra thick, draw, open rectangle fill=blue!40, shape=open rectangle,
  append after command={(\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[to path={rectangle (\tikztotarget)}, very thin] (\tikzlastnode.north east)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.1cm, Start chain/.style={start chain=ch#1 going below}, Start chain/.list={1,...,4}, node distance=+2pt]\ttfamily
\foreach \ch/\si in {1/{e, n, w, s},
                     2/{nws, ews, ens, enw},
                     3/{en, nw, ws, es},
                     4/{, full, ew, ns}}
  \foreach \Si in \si
    \node[at=(right:\ch), on chain=ch\ch, open rectangle sides=\Si] {\Si};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but received the following error:

```
! I can't find file `pgflibraryqrr.shapes.openrectangle.code.tex'.
<argument> ...input pgflibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex
```

I checked my MiKTeX installation, and the `epigraph` package is included therein.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: These are libraries made by our user [Qrrbrbirlbel](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) See his info box for details where you can find the libraries.

Comment: Thak you for your help. I have tried to see the info box of Qrrbrbrirlbel whithout any issu.

Comment: Follow the links provided in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140868/3954, download the libraries and save them somewhere TeX can find them (your current working directory, for example).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank's for your helps. I have dowloaded the zip file of  Qrrbrbirlbel. No results.

Comment: @Zbigniew: Did you put them into a local root/local exmf tree and updated the fontname database? [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483).