# Install TikZ Knots Library

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, mactex, tikzlibrary

I am trying to install the TikZ knots library, but I am having some trouble.

My computer is running Mac OS X 10.10.2 with MacTeX (but I don't remember the version/year).  `spath3` has been downloaded from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/spath3) and copied to my local texmf tree `$TEXMF/tex/generic/pgf`.  I copied some sample code from another post to try to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (0,1) -- (1,1);
        \draw[knot=black,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error I receive is

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
! $TEXMF/tex/generic/pgf/spath3/spath3.sty:103: LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
!
! Control sequence \__prop_split:NnTF undefined.
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!....................................................

1.103 \cs_generate_variant:Nn \__prop_split:NnTF
                                                 {cnTF}
?
```

I am aware of the post at [TeX SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187193/how-to-install-tikz-pgf-libraries) about cloning the Git repository for the library needed, but I don't know the correct address for the spath3 and/or knots library.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! First of all you should update your TeX distribution with TeX Live Utility.

Comment: And make sure you have the 2014 version. You can probably tell using the preference pane for managing TeX installations. Or TeX Live Utility probably tells you somewhere, but I've never used that.

Comment: An update of the OP's distribution solved this problem; it's unlikely that future visitors will experience the same problem, and is therefore considered off-topic.