# How to install just the most recent tikzmark package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, texmf, tikzmark, texmf-local

How do I install just the most recent version of the `tikzmark` package?

I tried to install texlive 2018, but it requires glibc 2.14, and my system (CentOS 6) only have glibc 2.12. I then installed the custom binaries for x86_64-linux-glibc2.12 but the system was unusable, nothing worked (e.g. IEEEtran), just the bare minimum (e.g. the article class). I reinstalled texlive 2016 and I am installing the more recent packages needed in my user texmf directory, but I don't know how to install the `tikzmark` package, as it is a library of the `tikz` package.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: see if https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187270/36296 helps, you can download the current library version from https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

I describe below what I have done to install the most recent version of the `tikzmark` package.

I have a tex file that needs the most recent version of the `tikzmark` package and generates an error when I try to compile with an old version of the package.

I searched in the log for "tikzmark" and discovered the file path for the package files already installed. In my system, /user/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzmark/tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex.

I downloaded the package from CTAN, unzipped it, and generated the `tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex` and `tikzmarklibrarylistings.code.tex` library files through the command `$ tex tikzmark.ins`.

I then created my tex user directory by issuing the following command in the terminal: `$ mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/tikzmark` and moved the generated files to there.

Done!

Credits to @samcarter!

Answer (score 1):

You can glibc 2.14 along with 2.12 following this post:
[How to update glibc to 2.14 in CentOS 6.5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299665/45852).

You can activate glibc 2.14 whenever you need by typing the last line given in the post.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib
```

So you can first install texlive 2018. Enter the above mentioned export command and then  try pdflatex.

This method worked for me. I didn't think adding the line `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib` to `.bashrc` was a good idea and hence I made another file `.latexrc` in the home folder and added this line there.  Doing `source ~/.latexrc` makes the terminal ready for running texlive commands.