# Connect nodes with parallel arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows, node-connections

My question is the same as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232440/connect-tikz-nodes-via-two-parallel-arrows).

Since the solution there demands a lot of adjustments and computations, I'd like to know if there is some new tool with a more powerful and simpler solution. Maybe some new `tikz` feature.

Also, one of solutions is not exactly *two arrows* but a *single double arrow*.

I'd like to move the arrows to get them parallels.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
 togo/.style={-to,line width=.4pt},
 tocome/.style={to-,line width=.4pt},
}
\node (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node (B) at (2,3) {$B$};
\draw[togo] (A) -- (B);
\draw[tocome] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, definitely a duplicate then ?

Comment: @cfr, the question, yes. But the answer below is different.

Comment: Yes, but that answer should be with the original question so that all the answers to the question are in one place. That's kind of the way the site works: one question can have many answers, but questions shouldn't repeat each other as it makes stuff harder for people to find. That's why questions get closed as duplicates, basically, so that all the information is together.

Comment: @cfr, I understand and agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No new tool, maybe (in the best) a new approach how to use existing ones for your MWE ...

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1,shorten >=#1},
      togo/.style = {-to,line width=.4pt,shorten <>=#1},
                    ]
\node (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node (B) at (2,3) {$B$};
\draw[togo=2mm] ($(A)!0.5mm!+90:(B)$)  edge ($(B)!0.5mm!-90:(A)$)
                ($(B)!0.5mm!+90:(A)$)   to  ($(A)!0.5mm!-90:(B)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]