# Combine -Triangle[left] and -Triangle[width=x]

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Is it possible to combine the `left` and `right` option for arrows with options like `length` and `witdth`? I’d like to create an path ending in a 45° angle like this:

[image]

So I tried to combine the above mentioned options, but the following MWE doesn’t give the expected result …

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
   angled line/.style = {
      line width = 2mm,
      -{Triangle[left,width=2mm,length=2mm]}
   },
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [angled line] (0,0) -- (2,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Do these options interfere with each other?

Comment: Try `-{.Butt Cap[slant=-1]}`.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks, thats a nice idea and works finde. Would you like to post it as an answer?! However I’m still interested why my approach doesn't work.

Comment: I am lazy to do so. You can write an answer. By the way, `left`/`right` does not work because you need an additional shift. See, for example, [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232440) to see how to achieve such shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in the comments by user Symbol 1:

> Try `-{.Butt Cap[slant=-1]}`