# doubling up on edges in a tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs, loops, draw

I made the following diagram based on an excellent, [very interesting answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493588/165801) to an earlier question.

[image]

```
%%% Preamble %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=9,tikz,rgb]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{/pgf/arrow keys/colorsize/.style={fill=#1,length=10pt, line width=0.5pt}}
\begin{document}
%%% Set total number of vertices here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\N{6}
%%% Set vertex coordinates here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{sunflower}{ % #1 is vertex index
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunangle{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunradius{sqrt(\sunindex)*50}
    \pgfpointpolar{\sunangle}{\sunradius}
}
%%% Set colours here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\globalcolorstrue
\def\definesuncolor#1{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunhue{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunsaturation{sqrt(\sunindex/\N)}
    \definecolor{sun#1}{Hsb}{\sunhue,\sunsaturation,1}
}
%%% Draw here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikz{
%%% Draw vertices %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach\i in{1,...,\N}{
        \definesuncolor{\i}
        \path(sunflower cs:\i)node(vertex\i)
            [circle,draw,minimum size=2cm,line width=6pt]{};
        \fill[sun\i](vertex\i)+(1pt,1pt)circle(1);
    }
%%% Draw edges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach\i in{2,...,\N}{
        \foreach\j in{1,...,\numexpr\i-1}{
            \path[scale=.666/sqrt(\N)]
                [shift=(vertex\i)](sunflower cs:\j)coordinate(X-\i-\j)
                [shift=(vertex\j)](sunflower cs:\i)coordinate(Y-\i-\j);
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun\j]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1](X-\i-\j)--(Y-\i-\j);
        }
    }
}
%%% End here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

I've played around with it a lot, but I still don't fully understand how it all pieces together. What I'd like to be able to do is make adaptations like this (drawn with Adobe Illustrator), while maintaining scalability, etc:

[image]

I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496462/165801) a while back, hoping it might help me come up with a way to incorporate the two concepts and produce a hybrid, but my skills just aren't quite there yet.

So specifically: Instead of all the nodes pointing to every other node (once), they just need to point to the first node (twice).

In the end I managed to get this far:

[image]

```
%%% Preamble %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=9,tikz,rgb]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}%,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{/pgf/arrow keys/colorsize/.style={fill=#1,length=10pt,line width=0.4pt,scale=1}}
\begin{document}
%%% Set total number of vertices here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\N{6}
%%% Set vertex coordinates here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{sunflower}{ % #1 is vertex index
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunangle{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunradius{sqrt(\sunindex)*50}
    \pgfpointpolar{\sunangle}{\sunradius}
}
%%% Set colours here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\globalcolorstrue
\def\definesuncolor#1{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunhue{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunsaturation{sqrt(\sunindex/\N)}
    \definecolor{sun#1}{Hsb}{\sunhue,\sunsaturation,1}
}
%%% Draw here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikz{
%%% Draw vertices %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach\i in{1,...,\N}{
        \definesuncolor{\i}
        \path(sunflower cs:\i)node(vertex\i)
            [circle,draw,minimum size=2cm,line width=6pt]{};
        \fill[sun\i](vertex\i)+(1pt,1pt)circle(1);
    }
%%% Draw edges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach\i in{2,...,\N}{
        \foreach\j in{1,...,\i}{
            \path[scale=.666/sqrt(\N)]
                [shift=(vertex\i)](sunflower cs:\j)coordinate(X-\i-\j)
                [shift=(vertex\j)](sunflower cs:\i)coordinate(Y-\i-\j);}
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun1]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1](X-\i-1)--(Y-\i-1);
    }
}
%%% End here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

So that's one down. Now I just need to double up on these edges and arrowheads but I'm not sure how to incorporate the following syntax into it:

```
\draw[arr=1em] ($(c)!1mm!90:(n\i)$) -- ($(n\i)!1mm!-90:(c)$);
\draw[arr=1em] ($(c)!1mm!-90:(n\i)$) -- ($(n\i)!1mm!90:(c)$);
```

Comment: If you only want to draw one connection, you do no longer need the loop over `\j`.

Answer (score 3):

Like this ?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz,rgb]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}%,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{/pgf/arrow keys/colorsize/.style={fill=#1,length=10pt,line width=0.4pt,scale=1}}

\begin{document}
%%% Set total number of vertices here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\N{6}
%%% Set vertex coordinates here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{sunflower}{ % #1 is vertex index
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunangle{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunradius{sqrt(\sunindex)*50}
    \pgfpointpolar{\sunangle}{\sunradius}
}
%%% Set colours here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\globalcolorstrue
\def\definesuncolor#1{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunhue{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunsaturation{sqrt(\sunindex/\N)}
    \definecolor{sun#1}{Hsb}{\sunhue,\sunsaturation,1}
}
%%% Draw here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikz{
%%% Draw vertices %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach\i in{1,...,\N}{
        \definesuncolor{\i}
        \path(sunflower cs:\i)node(vertex\i)
            [circle,draw,minimum size=2cm,line width=6pt]{};
        \fill[sun\i](vertex\i)+(1pt,1pt)circle(1);
    }
%%% Draw edges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach\i in{2,...,\N}{
        \foreach\j in{1,...,\i}{
            \path[scale=.666/sqrt(\N)]
                [shift=(vertex\i)](sunflower cs:\j)coordinate(X-\i-\j)
                [shift=(vertex\j)](sunflower cs:\i)coordinate(Y-\i-\j);
                }
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun1]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1]
                ($(X-\i-1)!1mm!90:(Y-\i-1)$)--($(Y-\i-1)!1mm!-90:(X-\i-1)$);
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun1]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1]
                ($(X-\i-1)!1mm!-90:(Y-\i-1)$)--($(Y-\i-1)!1mm!90:(X-\i-1)$);
    }
}

%%% End here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The sunflower code is extremely ingenious. It attaches the arrow to another node to the same spot of this node in a local coordinate system. So a node top right on the picture will connect to a top right position on the node. This is a beautiful idea!

With regards to your question, if you do not want to connect all nodes with each other, then you do not need the inner loop over `\j`. So you can label the coordinates by `\i` only, and all you need to do is to replace `(n\i)` and `(c)` by `(X-\i)` and `(Y-\i)`, respectively.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz,rgb]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}%,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{/pgf/arrow keys/colorsize/.style={fill=#1,length=10pt,line width=0.4pt,scale=1}}
\begin{document}
%%% Set total number of vertices here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\N{6}
%%% Set vertex coordinates here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{sunflower}{ % #1 is vertex index
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunangle{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunradius{sqrt(\sunindex)*50}
    \pgfpointpolar{\sunangle}{\sunradius}
}
%%% Set colours here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\globalcolorstrue
\def\definesuncolor#1{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunhue{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunsaturation{sqrt(\sunindex/\N)}
    \definecolor{sun#1}{Hsb}{\sunhue,\sunsaturation,1}
}
%%% Draw here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikz{
%%% Draw vertices %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach\i in{1,...,\N}{
        \definesuncolor{\i}
        \path(sunflower cs:\i)node(vertex\i)
            [circle,draw,minimum size=2cm,line width=6pt]{};
        \fill[sun\i](vertex\i)+(1pt,1pt)circle(1);
    }
%%% Draw edges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach\i in{2,...,\N}{
            \path[scale=.666/sqrt(\N)]
                [shift=(vertex\i)](sunflower cs:1)coordinate(X-\i)
                [shift=(vertex1)](sunflower cs:\i)coordinate(Y-\i);
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun1]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1]
                 ($(X-\i)!1mm!90:(Y-\i)$) -- ($(Y-\i)!1mm!-90:(X-\i)$);
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun1]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1]
                 ($(X-\i)!1mm!-90:(Y-\i)$) -- ($(Y-\i)!1mm!90:(X-\i)$);
    }
}
%%% End here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally would shrink the mini sun coordinate system since you have less connections and thus more space.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz,rgb]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}%,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{/pgf/arrow keys/colorsize/.style={fill=#1,length=10pt,line width=0.4pt,scale=1}}
\begin{document}
%%% Set total number of vertices here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\N{6}
\def\sunscale{50}
%%% Set vertex coordinates here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{sunflower}{ % #1 is vertex index
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunangle{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunradius{sqrt(\sunindex)*\sunscale}
    \pgfpointpolar{\sunangle}{\sunradius}
}
%%% Set colours here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\globalcolorstrue
\def\definesuncolor#1{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sunindex{#1-.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunhue{mod(\sunindex*16.18034,10)*36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sunsaturation{sqrt(\sunindex/\N)}
    \definecolor{sun#1}{Hsb}{\sunhue,\sunsaturation,1}
}
%%% Draw here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikz{
%%% Draw vertices %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach\i in{1,...,\N}{
        \definesuncolor{\i}
        \path(sunflower cs:\i)node(vertex\i)
            [circle,draw,minimum size=2cm,line width=6pt]{};
        \fill[sun\i](vertex\i)+(1pt,1pt)circle(1);
    }
%%% Draw edges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \def\sunscale{35} % redefine the sun coordinate system scale
    \foreach\i in{2,...,\N}{
            \path[scale=.666/sqrt(\N)]
                [shift=(vertex\i)](sunflower cs:1)coordinate(X-\i)
                [shift=(vertex1)](sunflower cs:\i)coordinate(Y-\i);
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun1]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1]
                 ($(X-\i)!1mm!90:(Y-\i)$) -- ($(Y-\i)!1mm!-90:(X-\i)$);
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun1]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1]
                 ($(X-\i)!1mm!-90:(Y-\i)$) -- ($(Y-\i)!1mm!90:(X-\i)$);
    }
}
%%% End here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could do that. On an unrelated note, Is it possible to add a `[bend right=40]` to the `/draw` command? I managed to do it with the `/path` command, but it doesn't have the arrowheads etc.

Comment: @tjt263 Sure: `\draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun1]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1]
                 ($(X-\i)!1.2mm!90:(Y-\i)$) to[bend left=20] ($(Y-\i)!1.2mm!-90:(X-\i)$);
            \draw[{Stealth[colorsize=sun1]}-{Stealth[colorsize=sun\i]}]
                [line width=.1]
                 ($(X-\i)!1.2mm!-90:(Y-\i)$) to[bend right=20] ($(Y-\i)!1.2mm!90:(X-\i)$);` You need to replace `--` by `to` for bending and friends. (you can replace 20 by 40 but I feel 20 looks better but this is just personal taste).