# Does the comment symbol % remove the carriage return at the end of the line?

Tags: comments

I find LaTeX a little bit inconsistent on this. Do the following experiments:

1. The code

   ```
   a.%
   b
   ```

   will produce `a.b`, while the code

   ```
   a.
   b
   ```

   will produce `a. b`. Looks like the comment symbol `%` has removed the carriage return at the end of the line. However,
2. The code

   ```
   \ta%
   u
   ```

   will produce an error (assuming you haven't defined `\ta`), much like

   ```
   \ta
   u
   ```

   but should the `%` here also remove the carriage return and combining the two lines into the meaningful `\tau`?

Comment: Erh, `a. % b` produces `a. `, under normal conditions, everything from `%` until the end of the line is ignored, including the newline at the end and the `%`

Comment: Also note that while \ta%⏎u doesn’t work, \tau%⏎dt is one way to produce τdt without a space (like \tau{}dt or {\tau}dt would).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like almost all programming languages, comment interpretation happens *after* tokenization.

`\ta%` produces the token `\ta` which will then fail to expand and genenerate an error before the `u` is seen at all.

this is no different from C or javascrpt etc where you can not use a comment in the middle of a function name, or XML/HTML where you can not use a comment in the middle of an element name.

Answer (score 19):

It's consistent with the rules. When TeX finds an end-of-record marker (end of line, if you prefer) as determined by the operating system, it throws it away together with possible trailing spaces and tabs; it then appends the current `\endlinechar`, usually ASCII 13 (represented in TeX as `^^M`). At this stage, tokenization has not yet taken place.

Now tokenization starts. Under normal conditions, `%` has category code 14 (comment) and ASCII 13 has category code 5. When TeX finds a character of category code 14, it throws away it with everything that follows on the line. A category code 5 character inserts a space, throws away what follows on the line and triggers looking for and removing spaces on the next line; if another category code 5 characters is found after this removal, a `\par` token is inserted, otherwise processing starts from the found character.

With the input

```
a%
b
```

the letters “a” and “b” are typeset without any intervening space, because the one inserted by `^^M` follows the comment character.

With the input

```
a
b
```

the space inserted by `^^M` is seen and inserted in the output.

For understanding what happens with

```
\ta%
u
```

one should remember how control sequences are formed. If the character following the backslash is a letter, TeX forms the name from all letters following it, stopping when a non letter (TeXnically, a character with category code different from 11) is found. If the character following the backslash is not a letter, that single character forms the control sequence name.

Since `%` has category code 14, it stops looking for the control sequence name, so you get `\ta` followed by `u`, not `\tau`.

Note that the rules imply that an input such as

```
a\
b
```

makes TeX form the control sequence `\^^M` and, indeed, plain TeX and LaTeX define `\^^M` to be the same as `\`  (backslash space).