# How to draw rounded corner grid in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

As the title describes, I want **only the biggest** rectangle to have **rounded corners**.

[image]

This is my code now

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thin, minimum size=0.4cm}]
    \begin{scope}
        \node[cell,fill=red!20] at (0,0) {};
        \node[cell,fill=red!20] at (0.8,0) {};
        \node[cell,fill=red!20] at (0.4,0.4) {};
        \node[cell,fill=red!20] at (0,0.8) {};
        \node[cell,fill=red!20] at (0.8,0.8) {};

        \node[cell,fill=blue!30] at (0.4,0) {};
        \node[cell,fill=blue!30] at (0,0.4) {};
        \node[cell,fill=blue!30] at (0.8,0.4) {};
        \node[cell,fill=blue!30] at (0.4,0.8) {};
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**I also wonder if there is a easier way to fill the grid with customized colors.**

Comment: Why do you have scope if it's not defining a demarcated part of the tikzpicture?

Comment: I only picked out a fraction of my code and delete the 'shift'.

Comment: I think the answer has to do with this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32869/90297

Comment: Would you like to write something into the nodes afterwards or do you just want this grid like this? If the latter, then just draw and fill, without using nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution without nodes, like said in my comment above:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
    
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \def\l{1} % length of one third of the grid
        
        \draw[rounded corners=3pt,fill=red!20] (A) rectangle++ (3*\l,3*\l);
        \foreach \x/\y in {1/0,0/1,1/2,2/1}
            \draw[fill=blue!20] ($(A)+(\x,\y)$) rectangle++ (\l,\l);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: grid with rounded corners]

Comment: This is perfectly what I want, thank you SebGlav.