# How to control borders of intersected nodes (rectangles)

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping, rounded-corners

I am trying to superpose 2 rectangles; one blue, one red, and have the intersection area with a mix of blue and red. I have problems with the borders though.

1. I am not getting the thickness of the borders correctly where rectangles intersect
2. when using rounded corners, I don't see how to nicely get 2 angles rounded (south west and north east) and 2 not.

Any idea?

[image: intersecting rectangles]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
box1/.style={draw=black, thick, rectangle,rounded corners, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=4cm},
box2/.style={draw=black, thick, rectangle, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=4cm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[box1, fill=red!10] (c2) at (0,0) {};
\node[box1, fill=blue!10] (c1) at (2,2) {};
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[color=blue!50!red!10, rounded corners, draw=black, thick] (2,2) rectangle (0,0);
\end{scope}


\node[box2, fill=red!10] (c2) at (8,0) {};
\node[box2, fill=blue!10] (c1) at (10,2) {};
\begin{scope}
\clip (8,0) rectangle (12,4);
\clip (6,-2) rectangle (10,2);
\fill[color=blue!50!red!10, draw=black, thick] (10,2) rectangle (8,0);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For your second problem (round only some corners) the shape `chamfered rectangle` with the option `chamfered rectangle corners` could be an alternative … See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28115/4918

Comment: You've asked six questions and still marked none of the answers as the accepted one. If one of the answers you received has solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark next to the answer text; this rewards the answerer and will be useful for future readers.

Comment: ah sorry I didn't know. I have been through them all and have marked all of them. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you `\clip` a part of the borders. Take a look at the following image. Figure a shows a black border, where the path of the border is shown in red. If you clip along the path you’ll get figure b showing that that the outer half of your black border is missing/clipped.

[image: clipping the line width]

### Possible solution

You could use transparency to overlay the two colors instead of clipping. Just set the colors with 100 percent and then set the opacity to the value you wan’t the colors to have. 10 percent means a value of 0.1. In the intersecting part the colors are mixed automatically and no clipping is needed. I used `fill opacity` instead of `opacity` to affect only the filling and not the border (`draw opacity`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    box1/.style={%
        draw=black, thick,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        minimum height=4cm,
        minimum width=4cm
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[box1, fill=red, fill opacity=0.1] (c2) at (0,0) {};
\node[box1, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.1] (c1) at (2,2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: overlaying colors]

Answer (score 9):

Tobi's answer shows the good way but there is a another way without `rectangle` and without `clip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
box1/.style={draw=black, thick, rectangle,rounded corners, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=4cm},
box2/.style={draw=black, thick, rectangle, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=4cm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[box1, fill=red!20]  (c2) at (0,0) {};
\node[box1, fill=blue!20] (c1) at (2,2) {};

\fill[green,thick]  (0+0.5*\pgflinewidth,2cm-0.5*\pgflinewidth)
                   {[rounded corners=3pt+0.5\pgflinewidth] -- ++(2cm-\pgflinewidth,0)} 
                    -- ++(0,-2cm+\pgflinewidth) 
                   {[rounded corners=3pt+0.5\pgflinewidth] -- ++(-2cm+\pgflinewidth,0)} 
                    -- cycle;  
\draw[thick]  (0+0.5*\pgflinewidth,2cm)
                   {[rounded corners] -- ++(2cm-0.5\pgflinewidth,0)} 
                    -- ++(0,-2cm) ;  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But if I use `\pgflinewidth` as part of a coordinate I must use the other part with a dimension, since `2+\pgflinewidth` = `2pt+\pgflinwidth`. Which is problematic if I set `x=0.456cm` for example. It’s the same problem with `2+1pt`. Is it possible to let TikZ read this as `2+(1pt)` and not `(2+1)pt` which it does? (Is this worth to be a new question?)

Comment: @Tobi In this case, you need to use the `calc` library for example  `($(0,2)+(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$)`

Comment: I have to say, Tobi's answer was rather sleek and I'll keep to it. But good to learn another way of doing. Thanks,

Comment: Tobi's answer is the better way. I  added a new answer only to give another way.