# Table with rounded corners

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I've taken an example of a very cool table from [here](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/graphics/tikz-table/) and I've made some changes to suit my needs, the problem is that the table it's not correctly rounded:
[image]

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to exist a rectagle element when you can only round some corners.
Here's MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=4cm, inner=2.5cm, outer=3.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % necesario para el símbolo €

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\setlength\textfloatsep{1.7\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength\intextsep{2\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.2\baselineskip}

\usepackage{environ} %lo usaré para crear el environ de tabla colorida

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Contiene el comando \midrule
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{%
   decorations.fractals%
  ,decorations.pathmorphing%
  ,shadows%
}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes} %para curvar texto
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning} %para los flow charts
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}



\colorlet{TablaBordeSuperior}{BurntOrange} %\definecolor{TablaBordeSuperior}{cmyk}{0,0.51,1,0} % BurntOrange
\colorlet{TablaBordeInferior}{Bittersweet} %\definecolor{TablaBordeInferior}{cmyk}{0,0.75,1,0.24} % Bittersweet
\colorlet{TablaCentroSuperior}{blue!1}
\colorlet{TablaCentroInferior}{blue!20}
\colorlet{FuenteCabeceraTabla}{white}
\newcommand{\fuentecabecera}[1]{\textcolor{FuenteCabeceraTabla}{\textbf{#1}}}

\newcommand{\encabezadoUnaLineaSuperior}{0.8}
\newcommand{\encabezadoUnaLineaInferior}{0.8}
\newcommand{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpoUnaLinea}{0.5em}
\newcommand{\encabezadoDosLineasSuperior}{1.3}
\newcommand{\encabezadoDosLineasInferior}{1.2}
%\newcommand{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpoDosLineas}{1.5em} %hay que aumentar el valor de 0.5 a 1.5 puesto que la cabecera ocupa dos líneas
\newcommand{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpoDosLineas}{2em}
\newcommand{\encabezadoTresLineasSuperior}{1.8}
\newcommand{\encabezadoTresLineasInferior}{1.8}
\newcommand{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpoTresLineas}{0.5em}
\newcommand{\encabezadoSuperior}{\encabezadoUnaLineaSuperior} %por defecto una línea
\newcommand{\encabezadoInferior}{\encabezadoUnaLineaInferior} %por defecto una línea
\newcommand{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpo}{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpoUnaLinea} %por defecto el de una línea

\newcommand{\encabezadoUnaLinea}{
    \renewcommand{\encabezadoSuperior}{\encabezadoUnaLineaSuperior}
    \renewcommand{\encabezadoInferior}{\encabezadoUnaLineaInferior}
    \renewcommand{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpo}{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpoUnaLinea}}
\newcommand{\encabezadoDosLineas}{
    \renewcommand{\encabezadoSuperior}{\encabezadoDosLineasSuperior}
    \renewcommand{\encabezadoUnaLineaInferior}{\encabezadoDosLineasInferior}
    \renewcommand{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpo}{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpoDosLineas}}
\newcommand{\encabezadoTresLineas}{
    \renewcommand{\encabezadoSuperior}{\encabezadoTresLineasSuperior}
    \renewcommand{\encabezadoUnaLineaInferior}{\encabezadoTresLineasInferior}
    \renewcommand{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpo}{\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpoTresLineas}}
%estos tres últimos comandos gestionan si el encabezado será de una línea, de dos o de tres

\newif\iflineaResaltado
\lineaResaltadofalse
\newcommand{\pieInferiorUno}{-5.2}
\newcommand{\pieInferiorDos}{3.45}
\newcommand{\resaltarPie}[2]{\lineaResaltadotrue\renewcommand{\pieInferiorUno}{#1}\renewcommand{\pieInferiorDos}{#2}}

\NewEnviron{tablacolorida}[2]{%
%  \vspace*{-2em}
    \begin{center}
        \captionsetup{type=table} %para que no me de error el posterior comando \captionof
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (tbl) {

            \BODY

            };
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                \draw[rounded corners,top color=TablaBordeSuperior,bottom color=TablaBordeInferior, draw=white] ($(tbl.north west)+(0.14,0)$)
                    rectangle ($(tbl.north east)-(0.13,\encabezadoSuperior)$); %el top color indica el color principal de la línea de cabecera %para tener encabezado de dos líneas (0.13,1.3)
                \draw[rounded corners,top color=white,bottom color=TablaBordeInferior,
                    middle color=TablaBordeSuperior,draw=white!20] ($(tbl.south west)
                    +(0.13,0.5)$) rectangle ($(tbl.south east)-(0.13,0)$);
                \draw[top color=TablaCentroSuperior,bottom color=TablaCentroInferior,draw=white] %el top color indica el color de inicio de las filas del medio, el "white" hace que el borde externo de las filas no se pinte
                    ($(tbl.north east)-(0.13,\encabezadoInferior)$) %con el parámetro 0.8 controlamos la altura de la línea de cabecera  %para tener encabezado de dos líneas (0.13,1.2)
                    rectangle ($(tbl.south west)+(0.13,0.2)$); %el 0.2 controla el grosor de la línea decorativa inferior

                \iflineaResaltado
                \draw[top color=TablaBordeSuperior,bottom color=TablaBordeSuperior, draw=white] ($(0,\pieInferiorUno)+(7.5,2)$)
                    rectangle ($(-0.5,1)-(7,\pieInferiorDos)$); 
                % ($(0,-4.8)+(7.5,2)$) ($(-0.5,1)-(7,3.1)$)
                % ($(0,-5.2)+(7.5,2)$) ($(-0.5,1)-(7,3.45)$) %una fila más abajo
                \fi
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{table}{#1} \label{tab:#2} 
    \end{center}
    %\vspace*{-1em}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tablacolorida}{Hitos del proyecto}{hitosProyecto}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{m{0.10\linewidth} m{0.34\linewidth} m{0.48\linewidth}}
        \arrayrulecolor{purple}
        \centering\fuentecabecera{Hito} & \centering\fuentecabecera{Fecha} & \centering\arraybackslash\raisebox{-0.3em}{\fuentecabecera{Descripción}} \\[+\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpo]
        \centering\textbf{H1} & \centering Mes 0 & \centering\arraybackslash Comienzo del proyecto \\ \midrule
        \centering\textbf{H2} & \centering 2 meses y 3 semanas & \centering\arraybackslash Fin del estudio del arte \\ \midrule
        \centering\textbf{H3}  & \centering 6 meses y 1 semana & \centering\arraybackslash Finalización de la plataforma de virtualización \\ \midrule
        \centering\textbf{H4}  & \centering 9 meses & \centering\arraybackslash Finalización de lo concerniente a DTN \\ \midrule
        \centering\textbf{H5}  & \centering 10 meses y 1 semana & \centering\arraybackslash Finalización de lo concerniente a CDN \\ \midrule
        \centering\textbf{H6}  & \centering 12 meses & \centering\arraybackslash Fin del Proyecto Fin de Carrera (PFC) \\[0.5ex]
    \end{tabularx}
\end{tablacolorida}

\resaltarPie{-9.7}{7.95}
\newcounter{paqueteTrabajo}
\newcounter{tarea}
\setcounter{paqueteTrabajo}{-1}
\newcommand{\filaRHpt}[7]{\addtocounter{paqueteTrabajo}{1}\setcounter{tarea}{1}\centering \bfseries{PT.\arabic{paqueteTrabajo}.}   & \centering \bfseries{#1} & \centering \bfseries{#2} €  & \centering \bfseries{#3} & \centering \bfseries{#4 €}  & \centering \bfseries{#5} & \centering \bfseries{#6 €} & \centering\arraybackslash \bfseries{#7 €} \\ \midrule}
\newcommand{\filaRHt}[7]{\centering T.\arabic{paqueteTrabajo}\arabic{tarea}.   & \centering #1 & \centering #2 €  & \centering #3 & \centering #4 €  & \centering #5 & \centering #6 € & \centering\arraybackslash #7 € \\ \midrule\addtocounter{tarea}{1}}
\newcommand{\filaRHTOTAL}[7]{\centering \fuentecabecera{Total}   & \centering \fuentecabecera{#1} & \centering \fuentecabecera{#2 €} & \centering \fuentecabecera{#3} & \centering \fuentecabecera{#4 €}  & \centering \fuentecabecera{#5} & \centering \fuentecabecera{#6 €} & \centering\arraybackslash \raisebox{-0.15em}{\fuentecabecera{#7 €}} \\}
\encabezadoTresLineas
\begin{tablacolorida}{Presupuesto de recursos humanos}{presupuestoRH}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{m{0.08\linewidth} m{0.08\linewidth} m{0.11\linewidth} m{0.08\linewidth} m{0.11\linewidth} m{0.08\linewidth} m{0.11\linewidth} m{0.11\linewidth}}
        \arrayrulecolor{purple}
        \centering\fuentecabecera{\underline{Tarea}} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\fuentecabecera{\underline{Recurso}}} \\ %[+\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpo]
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\fuentecabecera{FL}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\fuentecabecera{JMC}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\fuentecabecera{AM}} & \centering\arraybackslash\fuentecabecera{Coste} \\
        & \centering\fuentecabecera{CT}  & \centering\fuentecabecera{Coste} & \centering\fuentecabecera{CT}  & \centering\fuentecabecera{Coste} & \centering\fuentecabecera{CT}  & \centering\fuentecabecera{Coste} & \\ [+\espaciadoCabeceraCuerpo] %Para añadir un último elemento sería \centering\arraybackslash\raisebox{-0.25em}{\fuentecabecera{Total}} 
        \filaRHpt{7}{0}{0}{0}{312}{0}{0} %PRIMER PAQUETE DE TRABAJO
        \filaRHt{2}{0}{0}{0}{120}{0}{0}
        \filaRHt{1}{0}{0}{0}{72}{0}{0}
        \filaRHt{2}{0}{0}{0}{88}{0}{0}
        \filaRHt{2}{0}{0}{0}{32}{0}{0}
        \filaRHpt{8}{480}{1}{60}{408}{14688}{15228} %SEGUNDO PAQUETE DE TRABAJO
        \filaRHt{1}{60}{0}{0}{88}{3168}{3228}
        \filaRHt{1}{60}{0}{0}{72}{2592}{2652}
        \filaRHt{3}{180}{0}{0}{88}{3168}{3348}
        \filaRHt{3}{180}{1}{60}{160}{5760}{6000}
        \filaRHpt{9}{540}{2}{120}{336}{12096}{12756} %TERCER PAQUETE DE TRABAJO
        \filaRHt{2}{120}{0}{0}{72}{2592}{2712}
        \filaRHt{2}{120}{0}{0}{88}{3168}{3288}
        \filaRHt{1}{60}{0}{0}{88}{3168}{3228}
        \filaRHt{4}{240}{2}{120}{88}{3168}{3528}
        \filaRHpt{26}{1560}{1}{60}{192}{6912}{8532} %CUARTO PAQUETE DE TRABAJO
        \filaRHt{24}{1440}{0}{0}{160}{5760}{7200}
        \filaRHt{2}{120}{1}{60}{32}{1152}{1332}
        \filaRHTOTAL{50}{2580}{4}{240}{1248}{33696}{36516}[0.5ex] 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{tablacolorida}
\encabezadoUnaLinea

\end{document}
```

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28115/rounded-corners-only-at-one-side-of-a-tikz-node or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32867/tikz-rectangular-node-with-different-rounded-corners helps.

Comment: I already tried those withouth success :( maybe I did something wrong

Comment: Ah, sorry for the noise then.

Comment: See dcmst's answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples

Comment: It would be nice to create my tables with tcolorbox as it's simpler to use, but this particular fading may be difficult to do it (at least for a non expert like me). Take into account that the picture is not very good, I will upload one better asap

Comment: In fact it would be great to have such a table with tcolorbox instead of what I've done cos I've been in the need to do many hacks: one for heading of 2 lines, another for another of 3, more will be necessary for more lines, another if I want to remark something at the end of the table, etc. etc.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina would you know how to round the corners of the title part of a `tcolorcox` that is using `tabularx`?

Comment: @dustin yes, I would ;-) By the way, since I wasn't originally participating in the comments, I wasn't notified of your comment (I saw it just per chance).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One possibility using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and its built-in interaction with `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{times}

\renewcommand\rmdefault{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv} % Arial

\colorlet{TablaBordeSuperior}{BurntOrange}
\colorlet{TablaBordeInferior}{Bittersweet}
\colorlet{TablaCentroSuperior}{blue!1}
\colorlet{TablaCentroInferior}{blue!20}
\colorlet{FuenteCabeceraTabla}{white}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\tcbset{rtab/.style={
freelance,
frame code={
  \path[top color=BurntOrange,bottom color=Bittersweet] 
    ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north west) --
    ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north east) {[rounded corners]--
    ([yshift=3pt]interior.north east) --
    ([yshift=3pt]interior.north west)} -- cycle;
  \path[top color=TablaCentroSuperior,bottom color=TablaCentroInferior] 
    ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north west) --
    ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north east) --
    (interior.south east) --
    (interior.south west) -- cycle;
  \path[top color=TablaBordeInferior,bottom color=TablaBordeSuperior] 
    (interior.south west) --
    (interior.south east) {[rounded corners]--
    ([yshift=-5pt]interior.south east) --
    ([yshift=-5pt]interior.south west)} -- cycle;
  },
interior code={},
 }
}

\newcommand\fuentecabecera[1]{\textcolor{FuenteCabeceraTabla}{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  rtab=1,
  tabularx*={\arrayrulecolor{purple}}%
    {>{\bfseries}M{0.10\linewidth} M{0.33\linewidth}M{0.46\linewidth}}
]
\fuentecabecera{Hito} & \fuentecabecera{Fecha} & \fuentecabecera{Descripción} \\
\\[-1.7ex]
H1 &  Mes 0 & Comienzo del proyecto \\ 
\midrule
H2 & 2 meses y 3 semanas & Fin del estudio del arte \\ 
\midrule
H3 & 6 meses y 1 semana & Finalización de la plataforma de virtualización \\ 
\midrule
H4 & 9 meses & Finalización de lo concerniente a DTN \\ 
\midrule
H5 & 10 meses y 1 semana & Finalización de lo concerniente a CDN \\ 
\midrule
H6 & 12 meses & Fin del Proyecto Fin de Carrera (PFC) \\ 
\end{tcolorbox}

\vspace{1cm}% just for the example

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  rtab=2,
  tabularx*={\arrayrulecolor{purple}}%
    {>{\bfseries}M{0.10\linewidth} M{0.33\linewidth}M{0.46\linewidth}}
]
\fuentecabecera{Lin1} & \fuentecabecera{Lin1} & \fuentecabecera{Lin1} \\
\fuentecabecera{Lin2} & \fuentecabecera{Lin2} & \fuentecabecera{Lin2} \\
\\[-1.7ex]
H1 &  Mes 0 & Comienzo del proyecto \\ 
\midrule
H2 & 2 meses y 3 semanas & Fin del estudio del arte \\ 
\midrule
H3 & 6 meses y 1 semana & Finalización de la plataforma de virtualización \\ 
\midrule
H4 & 9 meses & Finalización de lo concerniente a DTN \\ 
\midrule
H5 & 10 meses y 1 semana & Finalización de lo concerniente a CDN \\ 
\midrule
H6 & 12 meses & Fin del Proyecto Fin de Carrera (PFC) \\ 
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The argument for the `rtab` style is used to control the number of lines that the table header will have.

In comments, it has been requested to have the possibility to provide a caption and label for the tables; here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{times}

\renewcommand\rmdefault{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv} % Arial

\colorlet{TablaBordeSuperior}{BurntOrange}
\colorlet{TablaBordeInferior}{Bittersweet}
\colorlet{TablaCentroSuperior}{blue!1}
\colorlet{TablaCentroInferior}{blue!20}
\colorlet{FuenteCabeceraTabla}{white}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\tcbset{rtab/.style={
freelance,
frame code={
  \path[top color=BurntOrange,bottom color=Bittersweet] 
    ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north west) --
    ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north east) {[rounded corners]--
    ([yshift=3pt]interior.north east) --
    ([yshift=3pt]interior.north west)} -- cycle;
  \path[top color=TablaCentroSuperior,bottom color=TablaCentroInferior] 
    ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north west) --
    ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north east) --
    (interior.south east) --
    (interior.south west) -- cycle;
  \path[top color=TablaBordeInferior,bottom color=TablaBordeSuperior] 
    (interior.south west) --
    (interior.south east) {[rounded corners]--
    ([yshift=-5pt]interior.south east) --
    ([yshift=-5pt]interior.south west)} -- cycle;
  },
interior code={},
 }
}

\newcommand\fuentecabecera[1]{\textcolor{FuenteCabeceraTabla}{\textbf{#1}}}

\NewEnviron{RCtable}[4][htbp]
  {%
    \begin{table}[#1]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[#2]\BODY\end{tcolorbox}%
    \caption{#3}
    \label{tab:#4}
    \end{table}
  }

\begin{document}

Como vemos en los cuadros~\ref{tab:pruebaa} y ~\ref{tab:pruebab}...
\begin{RCtable}{
  rtab=1,
  tabularx*={\arrayrulecolor{purple}}%
    {>{\bfseries}M{0.10\linewidth} M{0.33\linewidth}M{0.46\linewidth}}
}{Primer cuadro de prueba}{pruebaa}
\fuentecabecera{Hito} & \fuentecabecera{Fecha} & \fuentecabecera{Descripción} \\
\\[-1.7ex]
H1 &  Mes 0 & Comienzo del proyecto \\ 
\midrule
H2 & 2 meses y 3 semanas & Fin del estudio del arte \\ 
\midrule
H3 & 6 meses y 1 semana & Finalización de la plataforma de virtualización \\ 
\midrule
H4 & 9 meses & Finalización de lo concerniente a DTN \\ 
\midrule
H5 & 10 meses y 1 semana & Finalización de lo concerniente a CDN \\ 
\midrule
H6 & 12 meses & Fin del Proyecto Fin de Carrera (PFC) \\ 
\end{RCtable}


\begin{RCtable}{
  rtab=2,
  tabularx*={\arrayrulecolor{purple}}%
    {>{\bfseries}M{0.10\linewidth} M{0.33\linewidth}M{0.46\linewidth}}
}{Segundo cuadro de prueba}{pruebab}
\fuentecabecera{Lin1} & \fuentecabecera{Lin1} & \fuentecabecera{Lin1} \\
\fuentecabecera{Lin2} & \fuentecabecera{Lin2} & \fuentecabecera{Lin2} \\
\\[-1.7ex]
H1 &  Mes 0 & Comienzo del proyecto \\ 
\midrule
H2 & 2 meses y 3 semanas & Fin del estudio del arte \\ 
\midrule
H3 & 6 meses y 1 semana & Finalización de la plataforma de virtualización \\ 
\midrule
H6 & 12 meses & Fin del Proyecto Fin de Carrera (PFC) \\ 
\end{RCtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `RCtable` environment has one optional argument that can be used to specify the placement options (similar to the optional argument of the standard `table` environment), and three mandatory arguments: the first one, used for the options that build the table from the `tcolorbox`, the second one for the caption, and the third one to build the label (the label will have the form `tab:text`, where `text` is the string used in the third mandatory argument for `RCtable`.)

Comment: @Álvaro You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I have a question, how could I integrate a caption and label with your design? Like the caption I have in the MWE \captionof{table}{#1} \label{tab:#2}  could be ok. Hope you can modify your answer.

Comment: @Álvaro please see my updated answer; the new environment will be treated as a standard floating `table`, and allows you to provide placement specifiers, options for the `tcolorbox`, a caption and a label.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.22 of 2023-08-14) and TikZ. You need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv} % Arial

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\newcommand{\MyLine}{\Hline[tikz={line width=0.7pt,color=purple}]}

\begin{NiceTabular} 
  [
    width = 0.9 \linewidth , 
    cell-space-limits=1mm, 
    rounded-corners,
    rules/width = 0pt
  ]
  {>{\bfseries} X[m,c,10] X[m,c,33] X[m,c,46]}
  \Block[tikz ={top color = BurntOrange, bottom color = Bittersweet}]{1-*}{}
  \RowStyle[color=white,bold]{}
      Hito & Fecha & Descripción \\
  % In the following \Block, 'transparent' means 'transparent for the rules \Myline'
  \Block[transparent,tikz ={top color = blue!1, bottom color = blue!20}]{6-*}{}
      H1 &  Mes 0 & Comienzo del proyecto \\ \MyLine
      H2 & 2 meses y 3 semanas & Fin del estudio del arte \\ \MyLine
      H3 & 6 meses y 1 semana & Finalización de la plataforma de virtualización \\ \MyLine
      H4 & 9 meses & Finalización de lo concerniente a DTN \\ \MyLine
      H5 & 10 meses y 1 semana & Finalización de lo concerniente a CDN \\ \MyLine
      H6 & 12 meses & Fin del Proyecto Fin de Carrera (PFC) \\ 
  \noalign{\vspace*{-4mm}}  % in order to have a last row with small height
  \Block[tikz ={top color = Bittersweet, bottom color = BurntOrange}]{1-*}{}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]