# Rounded corner box with shading

Tags: boxes, framed

I wish to draw a rounded corner box (top-left side as a square, top-right side with 6pt radius curve and the bottom of two sides also with radius curve), in addition to that there should be shading, how can I get such a style? Is there any package available for this task?

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please post a minimum (working) example of your efforts so far, if any? The [TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package can do this job.

Comment: A tip for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128695/table-with-rounded-corners

Comment: `tcolorbox` package could help