# Creating a table with round corner

Tags: tables

I am trying to replicate the following image:

[image]

with the following latex code. I would like to have the table's corners rounded but I don't know how to get it done

```
\documentclass[]{article}
%Packages required for excel2latex generated tables
%
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
%For landscapte table
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.3ex}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
    \newcommand{\WideColWidth}{0.3}
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
   
    
             \begin{tabular}{|l|r|l|r|l|}
  \rowcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769} \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{Header}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{Header}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{Header}} \\
   \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}  \parbox{\WideColWidth\textwidth}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 
            \item 
            \item 
        \end{itemize}
    } 
&       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902} \parbox{\WideColWidth\textwidth}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
        \item 
        \item 
    \end{itemize}
}  &       &\cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}  \parbox{\WideColWidth\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
\end{itemize}
} \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}\cmidrule{5-5}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} \\
   \rowcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769} \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{Header}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{Header}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{Header}} \\
   \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}  \parbox{\WideColWidth\textwidth}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 
            \item 
            \item 
        \end{itemize}
    } &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902} \parbox{\WideColWidth\textwidth}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
        \item 
        \item 
    \end{itemize}
}  &       &\cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}  \parbox{\WideColWidth\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
\end{itemize}
}  \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}\cmidrule{5-5}    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look to the tcolorbox package, pag. 14 of the manual. It will put you in the right path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As starting point:

**Edit:**
Now with complete text in the table and slightly improved sticks layout:

[image]

Using `tcolorbox` and `enumitem` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, % <---
                 after=\end{minipage}\medskip}                   % <---
                            }

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[%
        raster columns=3,
        raster equal height,
        before=,after=\hfill,
        boxsep=3pt, left=3pt,   right=3pt,
        colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white,
        fonttitle=\large\bfseries,
        halign=left]

\tcbitem[title=Programming Courses]
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Pyton Courses
\item   Java Courses
\item   HTML Courses
\item   Blockchain Courses
\item   Cloud Courses
\item   DevOps Courses
\item   App Development Courses
    \end{itemize}
\raggedright\textbf{Browse All Courses in Programming}
%
\tcbitem[title=Business Courses]
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Finance Courses
\item   Marketing Courses
\item   International Business Courses
\item   Accounting Courses
\item   Supply chain Courses
    \end{itemize}
\raggedright\textbf{Browse All Courses in Business}
%
\tcbitem[title=Management Courses]
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Data Analysis Courses
\item   Leadership Courses
\item   Business Ethic Courses
\item   Business Analysis Courses
\item   Inovation Courses
    \end{itemize}
\raggedright\textbf{Browse All Courses in Management}
    \linebreak
\tcbitem[title=Communication Courses]
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Language Courses
\item   Grammar Courses
\item   Writing Courses
\item   ESL Courses
\item   Chinese Courses
\item   Spanish Courses
    \end{itemize}
\raggedright\textbf{Browse All Courses in Communication}
%
\tcbitem[title=Life Science Courses]
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Biology Courses
\item   Physic Courses
\item   Chemistry Courses
\item   Climate Change Courses
\item   Energy Courses
\item   Renewable Energy Courses
\item   Solar Energy Courses
\item   Astronomy Courses
\item   Environmental Science Courses
\item   Human Anatomy Courses
    \end{itemize}
\raggedright\textbf{Browse All Courses in Life Science}
%
\tcbitem[title=Engineering Courses]
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Mechanical Engineering Courses
\item   Urban Planing Courses
\item   Electronics Courses
\item   Geology Courses
\item   Structural Engineering Courses
    \end{itemize}
\raggedright\textbf{Browse All Courses in Engineering}
    \end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Works like a cham!

Answer (score 1):

From the beautiful table built by @GonzaloMedina --

[Table with rounded corners](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128695/table-with-rounded-corners)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv} % Arial

\colorlet{TablaBordeSuperior}{blue}
\colorlet{TablaBordeInferior}{blue}
\colorlet{TablaCentroSuperior}{blue!1}
\colorlet{TablaCentroInferior}{blue!20}
\colorlet{fontcol}{white}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\tcbset{rtab/.style={
        freelance,
        frame code={
            \path[top color=blue,bottom color=blue] 
            ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north west) --
            ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north east) {[rounded corners]--
                ([yshift=3pt]interior.north east) --
                ([yshift=3pt]interior.north west)} -- cycle;
            \path[top color=TablaCentroSuperior,bottom color=TablaCentroInferior] 
            ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north west) --
            ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north east) --
            (interior.south east) --
            (interior.south west) -- cycle;
            \path[top color=TablaBordeInferior,bottom color=TablaBordeSuperior] 
            (interior.south west) --
            (interior.south east) {[rounded corners]--
                ([yshift=-5pt]interior.south east) --
                ([yshift=-5pt]interior.south west)} -- cycle;
        },
        interior code={},
    }
}

\newcommand\fontcol[1]{\textcolor{fontcol}{\textbf{#1}}}

\NewEnviron{RCtable}[2][htbp]
{%
    \begin{table}[#1]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[#2]\BODY\end{tcolorbox}%
%       \caption{#3}
%       \label{tab:#4}
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{RCtable}{
            rtab=1,
            tabularx*={}%
            {>{\bfseries}M{0.3\linewidth}}
        }{}{}
        \fontcol{Details of Courses} \\
        \\[-1.7ex]
        \begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]
        \item Course1
        \item Course2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{RCtable}
    
\end{document}
```