# How to make single edges rounded with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am not good with tikz. I know that this question has already been answered in general (like, for example, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28115/rounded-corners-on-only-one-side-of-a-tikz-node)), but I was not able to transfer it to my example. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=17pt,
        ]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1.2cm,-1cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Which produces this type of rectangle around the whole page:

[image]

How can I make the NW and SE corners NON-rounded? So my special restriction is that I want the rectangle go all around the whole text, relative to the page size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just draw two different lines:

- one from the NW to EW to SE corners
- the other from the NW to SW to SE corners

With the `rounded corners` option, only the middle corner will become rounded:

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=17pt]
             ($ (current page.north west) + (12mm,-12mm) $)
          -- ($ (current page.north east) + (-12mm,-12mm) $)
          -- ($ (current page.south east) + (-12mm,12mm) $);
      \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=17pt]
             ($ (current page.north west) + (12mm,-12mm) $)
          -- ($ (current page.south west) + (12mm,12mm) $)
          -- ($ (current page.south east) + (-12mm,12mm) $);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

As Zarko says in the comments, a better solution is to use:

```
\SetBgContents{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=17pt, ]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (12mm,-12mm) $)
          -| ($ (current page.south east) + (-12mm,12mm) $)
             ($ (current page.south east) + (-12mm,12mm) $)
          -| ($ (current page.north west) + (12mm,-12mm) $);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: or shorter `\draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=17pt,
        ]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1.2cm,-1cm) $)
        -| 
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,2cm) $)
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,2cm) $)
        -| 
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1.2cm,-1cm) $);`

Comment: @Zarko +1 This is nicer than my solution. You should post it.

Comment: no, you bet me for 5 minutes ... you just add this possibilities to your answer ...