# Anchored path compiling indefinitely

Tags: tikz-pgf, rounded-corners, anchor

I want to make rounded corners on one side only like this:

```
\tikz{
\fill[red]
(0,0) +(8pt,8pt) arc (0:-90:8pt) -- (0,1) arc (90:0:8pt)
}
```

The points `(0,0)` and `(0,1)` in the above are placeholders. I actually want to use the lower and upper right corners of a node. Thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
\node[inner sep=8, fill=red](subh){
\parbox{2cm}{
some multiline text
}
\hspace{-8pt}
}
\fill[red]
(subh.below right) +(8pt,8pt) arc (0:-90:8pt) -- (subh.above right) arc (90:0:8pt);
}
\end{document}
```

This causes XeLaTeX to start an apparently neverending compilation. How to make it work? (I'm asking for a solution in this vein. What I'm actually going to try next, as I need the result quickly, is to make a 2x3 table with text spanning the first column, it and the middle cell of the second one having blue background and with TikZ-made quarter-circles in the rest.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Aren't you just missing some semicolons at the end of the paths? Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
\node[inner sep=8, fill=red,text width=2cm](subh){some multiline text};
\fill[red](subh.-45) +(8pt,8pt) arc (0:-90:8pt) 
-- (subh.45) arc (90:0:8pt);
}
\end{document}`

Comment: I am indeed! Somehow it works in the first snippet without one, despite the Wikibook. But adding it in the second one doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does my above code run through?

Comment: It unfortunately still doesn't work with your `\fill[red](subh.-45) +(8pt,8pt) arc (0:-90:8pt) -- (subh.45) arc (90:0:8pt);`.

Comment: My above code is a so-called minimal working example, it starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Can you turn you code into such an example?

Comment: Sure. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz{
\node[inner sep=8, fill=red](subh){
\parbox{2cm}{
some multiline text
}
\hspace{-8pt}
}
\fill[red]
(subh.below right) +(8pt,8pt) arc (0:-90:8pt) -- (subh.above right) arc (90:0:8pt);
}
\end{document}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89143/discussion-between-byteeater-and-marmot).

Comment: The `;` are still missing, so is`\end{document}`, `below right` is not a valid node anchor, nor is `above right`, and this works: `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\tikz{ \node[inner sep=8, fill=red](subh){ \parbox{2cm}{ some multiline text } 
\hspace{-8pt} };
\fill[red]{ (subh.-45) +(8pt,8pt) arc (0:-90:8pt) -- (subh.45)
arc (90:0:8pt) };}
\end{document}` And please add your example to the question (and not in a comment).

Comment: A semicolon is missing at the end of `\node[inner sep=8, fill=red](subh){
\parbox{2cm}{
some multiline text
}
\hspace{-8pt}
}`

Comment: @AndréC Yes, this is what I said twice above.

Comment: For a single rounded corner see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28118/121799 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32869/121799 .

Comment: Edited. The missing semicolon you're referring to seems to be required after `node` – I didn't realize that's a path too. Reading a tutorial misled me to `above`, `below` and `right`; I've replaced with `north`, `south` and `east`, respectively. What do the numbers in places of anchors mean? They seem to be in degrees, akin to Haskell's diagrams library. So, is -45 equivalent to `south east` and 45 to `north east`? And are there additional possibilities, e.g. 20?

But your example, @marmot, from #comment1192532_472993 still doesn't produce the desired effect.

Comment: ![rendered](https://i.imgur.com/7JE4RCD.png)

Comment: @ByteEater `45` and `north east` are not necessarily the same, so if you want `north east`, then take it. Yes, nodes are also paths. And yes, you can add any angle like 20. And I really think you might benefit from having a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28118/121799, where nodes with rounded corners on one side only are discussed. They come with the shape `rounded rectangle`, which is defined in the `shapes.misc` library.

Comment: @ByteEater `\node` is not part of the path. It is the TikZ syntax that requires that each instruction be ended with a semicolon.

Comment: @AndréC `\node` is  an abbreviation for `\path node` (p.222, pgfmanual, v3.1)

Comment: @PaulGaborit read the page 218 `Nodes are added to paths using the special path operation node. Nodes are not part of the path itself.`

Comment: @AndréC Do not confuse syntax and semantics. Syntactically, `\node` is a `\path` operation. This explains the addition of `;` at the end (as for all `\path`).