# Arrow doesn't touch block

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm currently drawing the following diagram:

[image]

For some reason one of the arrows do not touch the block IFOC. How do I fix that?

My code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

% Inclui subpacotes
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,patterns,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

% Define subcomandos
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum size=1cm, text centered]
\tikzstyle{circulo} = [draw, circle, minimum size=0.7cm, text centered]
\tikzstyle{triangulo} = [draw, thick, isosceles triangle, minimum height=1cm, isosceles triangle apex angle=60]
\tikzstyle{joint} = [draw, circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt]

\begin{document}

\tikzset{pics/transform/.style 2 args={code={%
\path (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/width}/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/height}/2)
 node[below right] (tl) {#2}
 rectangle
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/width}/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/height}/2)
 node[above left] (br) {#1};
 \node[pic actions,inner sep=0pt,fit=(tl)(br),path picture={\path[pic actions]
 (path picture bounding box.north east)
 -- (path picture bounding box.south west);}] 
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/name}){};
}},transform/.cd,height/.initial=2cm,width/.initial=2cm,name/.initial=}

\tikzset{pics/inverter/.style 2 args={code={%
\path (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/width}/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2)
 node[above right,scale=2] (bl) {#2}
 rectangle
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/width}/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2)
 node[below left,scale=2] (tr) {#1};
 \node[pic actions,inner sep=0pt,fit=(bl)(tr),path picture={\path[pic actions]
 (path picture bounding box.north west)
 -- (path picture bounding box.south east);}] 
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/name}){};
 \node at (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2) 
 [rectangle, above]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/title}};
}},inverter/.cd,height/.initial=2cm,width/.initial=2cm,name/.initial=,%
title/.initial=PWM Inverter}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm, >=latex']
\path pic[draw,rounded corners,text centered,transform/name=trans1] {transform={$abc$}{$qd0$}}
(0,-3) pic[draw,rounded corners,text centered,transform/name=trans2] {transform={$abc$}{$qd0$}}
(-3,0) node[block,minimum size=2cm](ifoc){IFOC};
\node at (0,-1.5) [joint](j4){};

% arrows
\draw[->] (-2,0.35)-- node{$v_{qs}^{\lambda}$} (-1,0.35);
\draw[->] (-2,-0.35)-- node{$v_{ds}^{\lambda}$} (-1,-0.35);
\draw[->] (-1,-2.65)-|node[above,pos = 0.15873]{$i_{qs}^{\lambda}$}(-2.5,-1);
\draw[->] (-1,-3.35)-|node[above,pos = 0.11494]{$i_{ds}^{\lambda}$}(-3.0,-1);
\draw[->] (ifoc)--(-1.5,-1.5)-|node[above,pos = 0.35]{$\theta^{\lambda}$}(trans1);
\draw[->] (j4)--(trans2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is due to the rounded corners. One solution might be to shift the coordinates, such as, `\draw[->] ([shift={(-0.5mm,0.5mm)}]ifoc.-45)--(-1.5,-1.5)-|node[above,pos = 0.35]{$\theta^{\lambda}$}(trans1);`

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150545/line-arrow-to-node-with-rounded-corners), and the solution to your issue is this: `\draw[->,shorten <= -2.5pt+\pgflinewidth] (ifoc)--(-1.5,-1.5)-|node[above,pos = 0.35]{$\theta^{\lambda}$}(trans1);` (copied from there and modified to fit your need).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the gap is due to the rounded corners. One way to fix the problem is to compute the intersection of the node boundary path with a continuation of the line to the center. This method also works if you want to terminate the line with an arrow, otherwise you could just use `clip`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Define styles: use \tikzset !
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum size=1cm, text
centered},
joint/.style={draw, circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt}}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{pics/transform/.style 2 args={code={%
\path (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/width}/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/height}/2)
 node[below right] (tl) {#2}
 rectangle
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/width}/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/height}/2)
 node[above left] (br) {#1};
 \node[pic actions,inner sep=0pt,fit=(tl)(br),path picture={\path[pic actions]
 (path picture bounding box.north east)
 -- (path picture bounding box.south west);}] 
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/transform/name}){};
}},transform/.cd,height/.initial=2cm,width/.initial=2cm,name/.initial=}

\tikzset{pics/inverter/.style 2 args={code={%
\path (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/width}/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2)
 node[above right,scale=2] (bl) {#2}
 rectangle
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/width}/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2)
 node[below left,scale=2] (tr) {#1};
 \node[pic actions,inner sep=0pt,fit=(bl)(tr),path picture={\path[pic actions]
 (path picture bounding box.north west)
 -- (path picture bounding box.south east);}] 
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/name}){};
 \node at (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2) 
 [rectangle, above]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/title}};
}},inverter/.cd,height/.initial=2cm,width/.initial=2cm,name/.initial=,%
title/.initial=PWM Inverter}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm, >=latex']
\path pic[draw,rounded corners,text centered,transform/name=trans1] {transform={$abc$}{$qd0$}}
 (0,-3) pic[draw,rounded corners,text centered,transform/name=trans2]{transform={$abc$}{$qd0$}}
 (-3,0) node[block,minimum size=2cm,name path=block](ifoc){IFOC};
\node at (0,-1.5) [joint](j4){};

% arrows
\draw[->] (-2,0.35)-- node{$v_{qs}^{\lambda}$} (-1,0.35);
\draw[->] (-2,-0.35)-- node{$v_{ds}^{\lambda}$} (-1,-0.35);
\draw[->] (-1,-2.65)-|node[above,pos = 0.15873]{$i_{qs}^{\lambda}$}(-2.5,-1);
\draw[->] (-1,-3.35)-|node[above,pos = 0.11494]{$i_{ds}^{\lambda}$}(-3.0,-1);
\path[name path=line] (ifoc.center) --(-1.5,-1.5);
\draw[name intersections={of=block and line},->] (intersection-1)--(-1.5,-1.5)-|node[above,pos = 0.35]{$\theta^{\lambda}$}(trans1);
\draw[->] (j4)--(trans2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]