# Remove tikz blank space at end of arrow edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-arrows

There's a mysterious blank space at the edges of the arrows between node 3 and node 9 below, whereas all the other edges are fine. How can I fix?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc, graphs, fit, backgrounds, positioning}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1,0.8,0}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.8,1.0,0.533}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,thick,black!50,text=black,
every new ->/.style={shorten >=0pt},
seqpoint/.style={
  rectangle,minimum size=4mm,rounded corners=2mm,
  inner sep=0,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  fill=myorange,
  font=\footnotesize\sffamily
},
func/.style={
  rectangle,minimum width=16mm,rounded corners=1mm,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  fill=mygreen,
  font=\ttfamily
},
parentfunc/.style={
  rectangle,minimum width=16mm,rounded corners=1mm,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  font=\ttfamily,
  append after command={node[below right = 3pt of \tikzlastnode.north west, font=\ttfamily] {#1}}
},
graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners}]
\matrix[column sep=4mm, row sep=4mm] { 
& \node (s1) [seqpoint] {1}; & \\
\node (s2) [seqpoint] {2}; & \node (s4) [seqpoint] {4}; & \node (s6) [seqpoint] {6};\\
\node (foo) [func] {foo}; & \node (bar1) [func] {bar}; & \node (bar2) [func] {bar};\\
\node (s3) [seqpoint] {3}; & \node (s5) [seqpoint] {5}; & \node (s7) [seqpoint] {7};\\
& & \node (baz) [func] {baz};\\
& & \node (s8) [seqpoint] {8};\\
& \node (s9) [seqpoint] {9}; &\\
& \node (quuxspace) []{}; & \\
& \node (s10) [seqpoint] {10}; &\\
& \node (tweedledee) [func] {tweedledee}; &\\
& \node (s11) [seqpoint] {11}; &\\
& \node (tweedledum) [func] {tweedledum}; &\\
& \node (s12) [seqpoint] {12}; &\\
& \node (s13) [seqpoint] {13}; &\\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node (quux) [parentfunc=quux, fill=mygreen!20, fit=(quuxspace) (s13) (tweedledee) (tweedledum)] {};
\node (isr) [parentfunc=isr, fit=(s1) (quux) (foo) (bar2)]{};
\end{scope}
\graph [use existing nodes] {
s1 -> s2 -> foo -> s3 -> s9;  
s1 -> s4 -> bar1 -> s5 -> s9;
s1 -> s6 -> bar2 -> s7 -> baz -> s8 -> s9 ;
s9 -> s10 -> tweedledee -> s11 -> tweedledum -> s12 -> s13;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that arrows connect squares surrounding your circles. Does changing nodes to circular help?

Comment: oh. Duh. Yeah, that would be it. I don't know why I was using rounded rectangles.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/rounded-corners-in-tikz-trees